# Wordpress side menu widgets

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, menu, widget

I'm working on a new WP site (3.5.1) and I'm trying to get a side menu set up.  I've got a main menu that is like this:

```
Top 1
  sub 1
  sub 2
  sub 3
Top 2
  sub 1
  sub 2
Top 3
```

I'm trying to take this and set it up so that I will get a menu on the side while I'm on Top 1 that will show:

```
Top 1
  sub 1
  sub 2
  sub 3
```

Top 2 would show itself and children as well.  This is something that is very easy to do in Joomla but I'm having a hard time finding out how to do this in WP.  I can add a custom menu to the sidebar but it will show the same menu all the time.  Meaning the `Top 1` menu would show on `Top 2` and `Top 3` pages.  Does anyone know of a good plugin that will do this?  Everything I find is stick menus and mega drop downs but I just need something simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was exactly what I was looking for.  Simple and easy to use.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-menu-wizard/

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of plugins for submenus.  Many of these appear to do what you want. [WordPress submenu plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tags/submenu).

Comment: Would you recommend any specifically?

Comment: This one is close but it is out of date:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/slmenuwidget/screenshots/

This can get the right menu elements but I am not actually including it in the sidebar so it doesn't adhere to the design of the template:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/codepress-menu/